# Display all available NLS timestamp formats in APEX select list

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a pretty standard looking APEX page where I have a select list for certain items that the user should select. These items are Timestamp format, date format, timezone.

Instead of creating my own tables and uploading definitions for these formats I would like to extract this information directly from the NLS tables. I was not able to do that, however. What would be the best way to display the full list of timestamp format, date format, and timezone in an APEX select list (not in a single select list, every format has it's own select list).

The closest I got was playing around with this query:
https://ferhatsengonul.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/to-show-nls-parameters-for-session-database-instance-together-by-pivot-and-listagg-on-11gr2/

But I could not find any information about displaying **all values** contained within those parameter lists.

Update> a few more details regarding the list of values I'm looking for...

The list of values that I would like to display to the user are available internally in APEX under the following location:
**Application -> Shared Components -> Globalization Attributes**

On that page there are the following fields:

- Application Date Format
- Application Date Time Format
- Application Timestamp Format
- Application Timestamp Time Zone Format

And clicking on those links it opens up the following list…and this is the functionality that I would like to have inside of my application as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the application builder, sourcing the export from the `/core` folder in your APEX download.

On page 506 (identified by using the builder), I can follow through to see the LOV they used

```
select d, r 
  from wwv_flow_format_masks
```

Drill further down to the view definition, and I can see it's just a bunch of union all statements over dual

```
select cast( d as varchar2(128) ) as d, r, t
  from ( select to_char((5234 + 10/100),'FML999G999G999G999G990D00') d, 'FML999G999G999G999G990D00' r, 'N' t from sys.dual
             union all
         select trim(to_char((5234 + 10/100),'999G999G999G999G990D00')) d, '999G999G999G999G990D00' r, 'N' t from sys.dual
             union all
         select trim(to_char((5234 + 10/100),'999G999G999G999G990D0000')) d, '999G999G999G999G990D0000' r, 'N' t from sys.dual
...
```

So this just represents a sample of what is available.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Scott. To others who might find it useful (or to future me :). You don't have to install APEX to access the data. The APEX installation can be downloaded unzipped and in the /core folder there are two files: apex_views.sql and views.sql, which contain the DDL for the "flow_*" views. For the timezone names I'm using select * from gv$timezone_names; ...or select * from v$timezone_names works as well.

Comment: Good point, I often forget that, too. But sometimes you first gotta know what you're looking for ;p